# How to save HTML elements behind an overlay HTML5 Canvas as an image?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

HTML 5 canvas is by default transparent. If it is over an HTML element, e.g. an image, that image is visible through canvas too. My question is, Is there a way to capture the area of background which is visible through canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't capture the canvas background just the content of the canvas.

Comment: Thanks for reply. is it possible to ask WHATWG to add this feature to canvas specification?